# Sublime text palavras com acento

Tags: sublime-text

Eu uso o sublime text no Windows 10, teclado (US) e não consigo colocar palavras com acentos (ex: ç, ã, (não != nao)). algum me ajuda?

Comment: Somente no sublime voce não consegue?

Comment: Em outros programas você consegue acentuar? Você abriu esta pergunta na mesma máquina na qual o sublime não funciona direito?

Answer (score 1):

Tenho o windows 10, 64 bits com teclado (US) e tenho o mesmo problema, não só no sublime text, mas em qualquer outro programa. Mesmo seguinte esse tutorial da microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/97738/using-us-int-l-keyboard-layout-to-type-accented-characters , não consegui fazer funcionar, o que faço é ter o ABNT (POR-PTB) instalado no painel de controle e quando preciso digitar esses acentos troco pra ele e uso o teclado como se fosse um ABNT, é chato, mas não encontrei outra maneira ainda. Outra opção é usar o teclado virtual, que também e chato